# How to clean settled grease from kitchen cabinets?

Tags: kitchens, cleaning

I like to fry a lot (I am not fat though :)) so there is quite a lot of grease and oil fume buildup on my kitchen cabinets.  I tried spraying and wiping, to no avail.  Any idea how I can clean settled grease and oil fumes from my cabinets effectively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A standard treatment for kitchen surfaces is to wipe it with a solution of TSP, an acronym for trisodium phosphate See http://www.ask.com/explore/what-tsp-cleaner.  It forms an **strong** alkaline (basic) solution that converts the grease to soap, making it easy to clean off.  The reaction is called saponification.  The same reaction takes place in drain cleaners and oven cleaners.

Be advised that the TSP will do the same thing to oils in your skin!  Use rubber gloves, eye protection, and whatever other precautions you find on the package.

A "Just Remembered" Edit:  TSP, and other alkaline solutions will attack aluminum surfaces!! Be warned...

Comment: TSP is great stuff for this situation. If you want something less caustic, aggressive, try some Dawn dish soap. I have had good success degreasing many items with it.

Answer (score 1):

look for pinksolution - non-toxic and I was amazed at the results. No detergent removed old grease like this one. Good for all cleaning around the house. It's very concentrated and a tub will last a very long time. Bought it from Costco in Canada, but look on their website (pinksolution.ca)